# Why ordered sequences can be reduced to sets?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I am trying to understand why ordered sequences can be reduced to basic sets.

I understand most of the following proof:

- Sequences can be defined as functions
- Functions are a special case of relations
- and Relations is a special case of sets
- Therefore sequences can be reduced to basic sets (this is what i don't get)

The issue I have is that relations is defined as follows:

> A relation Rp between A and B is defined as: Rp ⊆ A × B

Therefore relations makes use of the cartesian product operator, which also makes use of sequences.

Hence relations itself makes use of sequences. Therefore the proof that Sequences can be reduced to sets is flawed.

Please help me understand why sequences can be reduced to sets. Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: Relations (and therefore functions) make use of ordered pairs, which can be viewed as a special case of "sequence".  Ordered pairs suffice to define a Cartesian product of two sets.  So perhaps what you want to know is how to define an ordered pair using only set-based definitions?

Comment: exercise : how do you represent the function $f : \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}, z \to  (z+i)^2$ as a relation, then as a set ?

Comment: @reuns You represent the function $f$ as the relation that is the set of ordered lists of inputs and corresponding output: $\{\langle z, (z+i)^2\rangle \mid z\in \Bbb C , (z+i)^2\in\Bbb C\}$

Comment: ***Everything*** can be reduced to sets. But why is that a problem? Every line in your display can be reduced to a sequence of binary electric pulses representing it in a myriad of ways, so why are you using a display and not connecting two electric cables to your fingers?

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be one step missing:

- ordered pairs (the elements of the cartesian products) can be reduced to sets

Following Kuratowski we can [*define*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair)
$$ (x,y):=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$$
which may look somewhat arbitrary, but conveys the essetnial notion of ordered pair: $(x,y)=(u,v)\iff x=u\land y=v$.

Comment: Yes. Even if an ordered pair is *a* sequence, we can give it a *primitive definition* then use that to produce a more *general definition* for all sequences.  In essence: you've got to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore relations makes use of the cartesian product operator, which also makes use of sequences.

What.   Ah... Yes, that is a just *wee* bit recursive, isn't it now?

The Cartesian product of sets $\rm A, B$ is defined as: $\mathrm A{\times}\mathrm B = \{\langle a,b\rangle \mid a\in\mathrm A \,\wedge\, b\in\mathrm B\}$

That is, it is the set of all *ordered pairs* whose members are each from the sets under discussion (in the given order).

Now, an ordered pair *is* a primitive sequence, given that "*A sequence is an ordered collection of objects in which repetitions are allowed.*"

A sequence can be considered a function (mapping index to value).   Such functions can be represented as relations (in this case the set of index, value *ordered pairs*).   Such a relation is a subset of the Cartesian product of the set of indices and the set of values.   And a Cartesian product is ...

And round and round it goes.

So, really, we can only say: The *defined concept* of sequences can be reduced to that of basic sets, *if* we first accept a *[primitive notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_notion)* of "ordered pair".

Comment: Why do you need to accept ordered pairs as a primitive notion?

Comment: A *primitive notion* is one that is not defined in terms of prior constructs, but as you commented on in Hagen's Answer, the *ordered pair* can be defined in terms of the simpler notions of sets with one and two elements.  Other constructions of order pairs in terms of the primitive *set membership* are possible.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence is a function $f:\mathbb Z^+ \to \mathbf S$.

$f:\mathbb Z^+ \to \mathbf S$ is a special case of a relation
$f \subset \mathbb Z^+ \times \mathbf S.$

The cartesian product $\mathbb Z^+ \times \mathbf S$ is the set
$\{(x,y): x \in \mathbb Z^+$ and $y \in \mathbf S \}$

I'm not sure what you mean by "basic".

It seems that you are trying to use the category theory definition of direct product, which is a "generalization" of cartesian products but is not the same thing.