# Ordered Sequence to Set Definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

From [Why ordered sequences can be reduced to sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378756/why-ordered-sequences-can-be-reduced-to-sets)

$$ (x,y):=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$$

What's the more general equation to convert ordered sequences to sets?

What about $(x, y, z, ...)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options: either define $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ inductively as $(x_1,(x_2,\ldots,x_n))$, or define it as $\{\{x_1\},\{x_1,x_2\},\ldots,\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\}$, and define $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$, therefore, to be $\{\{x_1\},\{x_1,x_2\},\ldots,\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\},\ldots\}$.

Comment: ah, makes much more sense when I see the big picture.